# Does MS SQLServer support 2-phase commit?

Tags: sql-server, rdbms, 2phase-commit

To serve as RM (resource manager) in distributed transaction, DBMS must implement 2-phase commit. Like in PostgreSQL, when you first "pre-commit" local transaction:

```
PREPARE TRANSACTION 'foo'
```

then commit it:

```
COMMIT PREPARED 'foo'
```

My question is: does MS SQLServer supports such functionality?

Comment: Yes - Sql Server can enlist in [DTC / XA transactions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: @StuartLC Didn't try yet but it seems to be exactly what I need. Thanx!

Comment: Distributed transaction syntax for Sql Server is `BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION`. Also, FWIW if you have a .Net App, you should look into `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`, which will automatically manage transactions, escalating to distributed only if needed - this is a good thing, as distributed transactions can be lock-heavy.

Comment: @StuartLC no, I have a Java application and looking for SQL Server implementation as resource manager, not transaction manager. Though, link above is very helpful.